# Drawing circles in 3D

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

Basically I want to do a 3D plot of 100 circles with different radii and on a new height plane(h) for each circle. The radius increase for each circle(constant increase) and h increase constantly.

The problem with my code is that I plot 100*100 circles instead of just 100, as desired.

```
for r=1:1:100              
    t=linspace(0,2*pi);    
    x=r*cos(t);
    y=r*sin(t);
    for h=100:100:10000
    z=h * ones(1, length(t));
    plot3(x,y,z);
    if r == 1 && h == 100
        hold on;
        % Enlarge figure to full screen.
        set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
    end
    drawnow;
end
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got one loop inside another and each loop has 100 iterations so you're going to end up with `100*100` of something.

I suggest you remove the inner loop, the one beginning `for h=100:100:10000` and replace the statement

```
z=h * ones(1, length(t));
```

by

```
z = 100 * r * ones(1, length(t));
```

If I've understood your code correctly this is probably what you ought to be doing.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it's enough to just change the statement to get it done. However, the execution is extremely slow. I'll try if the  execution will speed up when removing the inner loop. I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you only change the statement as I suggested you should get the result you want.  What then is the purpose of the `h` loop ?

Comment: None actually. So the issue of MATLAB being slow is in most cases a matter of code?

Comment: If you leave in the loop `for h = 100:100:10000` and change the code as I suggested then your program will compute the same results 100 times. I'm not sure that it is sensible to conclude, from that, that Matlab is slow.

Comment: I understand, of course it's better to remove the inner loop.